# Angular: nested form "Cannot read property 'length' of null"

Tags: angular

I have a nested form, here are the formcontrols:

```
this.newRequest = this._fb.group({
    requestType: [],
    tripType: [],
    feeders: [''],
    directFlight: [],
    departure: [''],
    arrival: [''],
    depDate: [''],
    arrDate: [''],
    nbPax: ['', [Validators.max(95), Validators.min(1), Validators.pattern('^[0-9]+$')]],
    class: [''],
    daterangeToggle: [],
    viaToggle: [],
    detailsToggle: [],
    roundway: this._fb.array([
        this.initRoundway()
    ])
});  

initRoundway() {
    return this._fb.group({
        daterangeOutFrom: [],
        daterangeOutTo: [],
        viaOut: this._fb.array([]),
        viaIn: this._fb.array([]),
        flights: this._fb.array([
            this.initFlights()
        ])
    });
}

initFlights() {
    return this._fb.group({
        class: ['', Validators.required],
        flightNb: [''],
        timeMin: [''],
        timeMax : ['']
    });
}
```

I have problems accessing `viaOut` and flightNb.

I tried:

```
const control1 = <FormArray>this.newRequest.controls['roundway'];
if (control1.controls['viaOut'].length===0) {...}
```

And also:

```
const control1 = <FormArray>this.newRequest.get('roundway.viaOut');
if (control1.length === 0) {...}
```

But both don't work, I get an error `"Cannot read property 'length' of null"`

**EDIT**

Here is the output of console.log(control1) using the first code.

[image: Output]

Thanks.

Comment: Your missing `.value` in `this.newRequest.get('roundway.viaOut').value`. If that doesnt solve your problem please add more code. Where are you initialising the form "this.newRequest"

Comment: Also remember roundway is a formArray. So using the selector "roundway.viaOut" is never going to work. What output do you get from logging console.log(control); in your first example? That could give more info on what you need to do.

Comment: @MikeBovenlander : When Itry this I get the error "Cannot read property 'value' of null". Also, the code concerning newRequest is in   ngOnInit() {}

Comment: @user3492940 I edited the post with the output

Comment: Here is your case `newRequest.get('roundway.0.viaOut').length` See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46169753/angular-4-property-push-and-controls-does-not-exist-on-type-abstractcontro/46169964#46169964

Comment: Thanks @yurzui that fixed it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi please try this,

```
const control1 = <FormArray>this.newRequest.controls['roundway'];
if (control1.controls['viaOut']['controls'].length===0) {...}
```

OR

```
const control1 = <FormArray>this.newRequest.get('roundway.0.viaOut');
if (control1.length === 0) {...}
```